# Alternatives to TimeBridge?

Tags: tracking, meetup

I love the idea to have a web app that let me first plan a meeting, and then write notes and action to be made that was discussed in that meeting. But TimeBridge forces me to send emails to the people that will be in that meeting (that's because is primary used as multi user schedule). Most of my clients don't know anythig about internet, web apps, etc.

Is there an alternative that is like timebridge, but easier to use in "solo" mode?

the option to send meeting reports is a big plus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can look at [alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/software/timebridge/) for answers on alternatives.

One alternative they list is [Tungle.me](http://Tungle.me), a service that from my knowledge lets you add meetings with persons offline.